# Calling a jquery function on row click of Asp.Net Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my project , in one of my pages I have a `GridView` and I am using the following line to handle row click

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='Default.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
```

This is working fine , however I have a requirement to call a jquery function which displays a popup , here is the function

```
function ShowDialog(modal) {
        $("#popupmask").show();
        $("#popup").fadeIn(300);

        if (modal) {
            $("#popupmask").unbind("click");
        }
        else {
            $("#popupmask").click(function(e) {
                HideDialog();
            });
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I call jquery function on row click of `Asp.Net Gridview`
Thanks

Comment: check this http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/324_Make_GridView_Row_Selectable_or_Clickable_using_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr").click(function(){
    alert("Row clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that i am showing you one simple way to do that.

First you need to wirte these lines in your asp.net Grid code.

```
<RowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="myrow" />
```

then your grid looke like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <RowStyle CssClass="one" />
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="one" />

   </asp:GridView>


<script >
    $(function () {
        $('.myrow').click(function () {
           //below line get 1st td of your selected tr of the grid
            console.log($(this).children().eq(0));

            alert('clicked ');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to specify the `AlternatingRowStyle`. I think this just overrides the `RowStyle` when applied.

Comment: Thats better to use alternateRowStyle . . .